# service.foo is not a function Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

my component isn't recognizing a function in a service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LocationService {

  private coordinates: any;
  constructor(
    private toastCtrl: ToastController
  ) { }

  set setCoords(coords: any) {
    this.coordinates = coords;
    this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: `Coordinates Assigned ${this.coordinates.latitude},${this.coordinates.longitude}`
    }).then(alertCtrl => {
      alertCtrl.present();
    });
  }
  get getCoords(): any {
    return this.coordinates;
  }
}
```

Here is my component (`app.component.ts`) where I'm trying to access my function

```
  Geolocation.getCurrentPosition({ enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 5000 }).then(loc => {
        alert('Latitude: ' + loc.coords.latitude + 'Longitude: ' + loc.coords.longitude);
        console.log('Location: ', loc);
        this.locationService.setCoords(loc);
      }).catch(err => {
        alert(err);
        console.log('Error while getting location:', err);
      });
```

But unfortunately get the following error, to which I've absolutely no clue why it's not detecting the function, although everything seems to be correct. I've tried to restart the app run it again, but nothing working.

```
Error while getting location: TypeError: this.locationService.setCoords is not a function
    at app.component.ts:56
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:359)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:34201)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:358)
    at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:124)
    at zone-evergreen.js:855
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:34182)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
```

Comment: It's *not* a function, you explicitly made it an accessor.

Comment: thank you so much, I just answered my own question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is easy to spot, you are using getters and setters:

```
export class LocationService {

  private coordinates: any;
  constructor(
    private toastCtrl: ToastController
  ) { }

  set setCoords(coords: any) {
    this.coordinates = coords;
    this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: `Coordinates Assigned ${this.coordinates.latitude},${this.coordinates.longitude}`
    }).then(alertCtrl => {
      alertCtrl.present();
    });
  }
  get getCoords(): any {
    return this.coordinates;
  }
}
```

If you want it to be a function you should declare it without the `get` and `set` keyword in front of the functions

Answer (score 1):

I got it wrong, its just a accessor and I was accessing it in a wrong way, i.e. the correct way was to access it without brackets .